# CSS Modules Value is not retrieved

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm using CSS Modules in my react application. Depending on the props value, if it is blue or white, i want to use the respected class from the "styles" import. However, when i run the code and inspect the p element, i see that class name is shown as "styles.blue-text" for example, but the value of it is not retrieved from the respecting css file. Why it is not applied, although the class name is correctly fetched.

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react"
import DarkBlueRightArrow from "../../../resources/images/shared/darkblue-right-arrow.svg"
import styles from "./LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton.module.css"


const LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton = props => {

  const [color,setColor] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
      if(props.color === "white")
        setColor("styles.white-text")
      if (props.color === "blue")
        setColor("styles.blue-text")
  });

  return (
    <a href={props.detailLink}>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-ceter">
        <img className={styles.icon} src={DarkBlueRightArrow} alt="" />
        <p className={color}>{props.text}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  )
}

export default LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton
```

Comment: I don't see any styled-components in the code you provided. Maybe you're confusing CSS modules with CSS-in-JS?

Comment: You are not using styled components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is not valid when used with dot object notation. You have to use the bracket notation instead.

Also state is not required when it can be calculated with props.

```
...
const LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton = props => {

  /* const [color,setColor] = useState("") */

  /* useEffect(() => {
      if(props.color === "white")
        setColor("styles.white-text")
      if (props.color === "blue")
        setColor("styles.blue-text")
  }); */

 const color = props.color === "white" ? styles['white-text'] : styles['blue-text']

  return (
    <a href={props.detailLink}>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-ceter">
        <img className={styles.icon} src={DarkBlueRightArrow} alt="" />
        <p className={color}>{props.text}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  )
}
...
```

That's why CSSModules prefer naming class names in camelCase, so to avoid the bracket notation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer, I tried the code you provided but sadly its not working. I have .blue-text {} class with color code in my css module file, and when i use your code, it behaves the same like how i couldn't solve it. :/ sadly.

Comment: Can you show how you are rendering `LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton` component?

Comment: <LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton color='white' text='IT is also working' />

i call it in another page as above. when i inspect it, the text color is black meaning none of the blue or white color css classes are applied sadly

Comment: Looks fine to me. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-css-modules-forked-c2ghr?file=/src/index.js) highlighting the above code and it works fine there.

Can you confirm if you do have the proper css declaration for 'white-text' and 'blue-text' in your css? If it's still not working, maybe produce a codesandbox for further debugging.

Comment: removing - naming from the css classes and making them camel case fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer with the `-` way when dealing with CSS modules, simply adding `.toString()` definitely works.

```
const LeftSidedCircularDarkBlueArrowButton = props => {
  // ...

  const color = props.color === "white" 
    ? styles['white-text'].toString()
    : styles['blue-text'].toString()

  return (
    <a href={props.detailLink}>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-ceter">
        <img className={styles.icon} src={DarkBlueRightArrow} alt="" />
        <p className={color}>{props.text}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  )
}
```

Without `.toString()`, it doesn't return a class and only returns the initial state you set it in and vice versa.